# Query an SQL table to return the value of the same row based on user input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, forms

Assume I have the following SQL table:

```
DATE1      |    DATE2
--------------------------
4/21/2012  |  3/SHAVAT/5777
4/22/2012  |  4/SHAVAT/5777
4/23/2012  |  5/SHAVAT/5777 etc...
```

What I am trying to do is - based on user input from a form AUTOMATICALLY have the second field filled out. Whether they do field 1 or 2 first.

SO I started to do this:

```
<input type="text" id="dname" name="dname" value="<?php echo $myrow['DATE1']?>"
<input type="text" id="dname" name="dname" value="<?php echo $myrow['DATE2']?>"
```

The PhP I am trying to use is

```
<?php
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT heb_date, greg_date FROM calendar" )
?>
```

And that's about as far as I have gotten. I would LIKE it to check against the table, find the input date of either field, then populate the OTHER field with that result. Essentially, if Timmy puts in 4/12/2007 it listens, checks against the DB, then whatever date is on that same ROW but in the second column, returns it to the other field, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `WHERE` clause here:

```
SELECT heb_date
FROM calendar
WHERE greg_date = '2007-12-04'
```

You also might need to handle the case where the `heb_date` cannot be found, though ideally your calendar table should not have any holes in it.

Comment: Can it be written to include the users variable?

Like

SELECT heb_date
FROM calendar
WHERE greg_date = '$date1'

Comment: @SeanRawles Yes, this should work, but you should look into using parametrized queries.  If you directly embed `$date1` into your `WHERE` clause, you leave open the chance for SQL injection (where bad users find tricks to get info they should not have, or even try to delete your database).

Answer (score 0):

What the below code does is give you a form that allows you to fill in a date. It will then update your table with that date and set it to `heb_date` and `greg_date` if either of those columns matches the entered date.

Your HTML

```
<!-- Form -->
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value="<?= $row['greg_date']; ?>" />
</form>
```

#### Your PHP/SQL

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $date = $_POST['dname'];

    $stmt = "UPDATE calendar
    SET heb_date='".$date."',
    SET greg_date='".$date."'
    WHERE heb_date='".$date."'
    OR greg_date='".$date."'
    ";

    // if you would like to select the dates however
    $stmt = "SELECT
    heb_date,
    greg_date
    FROM calendar
    WHERE greg_date = '".$date."'
    OR heb_date = '".$date."'
    ";
}
```

#### Update

It's not entirely clear to me. If you mean that you want to match the date against the row and return another date, do the following.

```
// Do the following if the form submits
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $date = $_POST['dname'];

    $stmt = "SELECT
    heb_date,
    greg_date
    FROM calendar
    WHERE greg_date = '".$date."'
    OR heb_date = '".$date."'
    ";

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($stmt);

    // Not sure if its an array that is returned, but this will get the first value.
    $row = current($myrows);

    // Let's check which date is different
    if ($date != $row['greg_date']) {
        $date = $row['greg_date'];
    } else {
        $date = $row['heb_date'];
    }
}
?>

<!-- Form -->
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value="<?= $date; ?>" />
</form>
```

## Update with AJAX

#### index.html

```
<!-- Form -->
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value="<?= $date; ?>" />
</form>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('focusout', '#dname', function () {
        var dname = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getdate.php',
            data: {
                'dname': dname
            },
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                $('#dname').val(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

#### getdate.php

```
// Do the following if the form submits
if (isset($_REQUEST['dname'])) {
    $date = $_REQUEST['dname'];

    $stmt = "SELECT
    heb_date,
    greg_date
    FROM calendar
    WHERE greg_date = '".$date."'
    OR heb_date = '".$date."'
    ";

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($stmt);

    // Not sure if its an array that is returned, but this will get the first value.
    $row = current($myrows);

    // Let's check which date is different
    if ($date != $row['greg_date']) {
        $date = $row['greg_date'];
    } else {
        $date = $row['heb_date'];
    }

    echo $date;
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Comment: what if the inputs are already in a form doing different actions?

Comment: No problem. The form was just an example.

Comment: I am sorry I am just learning this stuff. So I add this to the PhP and disregard what I have already?

I'm assuming that ".$date." fields should be the form names?

Comment: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') Means it only happens upon submit, yes? Not when the user tabs off or something?

I am sorry if I am not being clear. Front end guy having to do heavy lifting under the gun.

Comment: You are correct. The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is POST if you submit your form.

Comment: Dang. They want it to happen like on the tab or user goes to next form area. Is there a request_method for that circumstance?

Comment: You will need to use ajax to do that. `jQuery` is a usefull front end library. Remember that PHP is a server side language and you cannot execute script upon certain events in the browser.

Comment: Maybe I should look for a JQUERY answer then.

Comment: I am assuming the ".$date." variable should be replaced with my form area names?

Comment: You should change `$date = $_REQUEST['dname'];` to `$date = $_REQUEST['your_form_element_name'];`

Comment: This is what Console says. Again, seems like an easy thing but apparently it's not:

http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/getdate.php?dateenglish=9%2F21%2F2023 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Did you create the file 'getdate.php' ?

Comment: yes, but I added an absolute path this time. And then this came out:

Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in /home/msparks/public_html/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/getdate.php on line 14

Comment: Okay so adding the wp_load statement seemed to clean the fatal error BUT now the date just disappears. Odd.